# How to move Beamer headline below frametitle?

Tags: beamer, formatting, header-footer, positioning, navigation

I am creating my own Beamer theme based on the Berlin theme and what I want to do is to move the navigation bar below the frametitle, instead of the default position (i.e., top of page, above everything).

For example, the following picture and code uses the Berlin theme, which creates a navigation bar in the headline on top of the frame.  How can I move the frametitle to the top of frame and move the navigation bar below the frametitle?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
\section{First Sec}
\begin{frame}{First Frame Title}First Section\end{frame}
\section{Second Sec}
\begin{frame}{Second Frame Title}Second Section\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I remember that I copy and `.sty` file and modified some things, maybe you can do it ... in `.sty` file there is the design ...

Comment: @juanuni, thanks for your response.  Which .sty are you referring to? The beameroutertheme one?  Any idea which command will do the magic?

Comment: Well, two ways: 1) you can make the changes for your Berlin theme (forever :v ), I dont remember if the change what you want is in `beameroutertheme.sty` or `beamerinnertheme.sty`, you can read the Till Tantau's beamer guide ... 2) rename a copy of your Berlin theme, make the changes for your design and install this "new theme" like another LaTeX package ... I don't remember the commands, but if you identify the `.sty` you can read the design, is not hard to differentiate between the design and commands defined in the `.sty` file. Regards ...

Comment: @juanuni, thanks.  I was able to find a way to get it done, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a while and could not find an answer, I doubt if there is any straightforward command to do this.  However, I figured out a workaround to do this, for those who might be interested.

First, you need to know which outer theme (.sty file) your beamer theme uses.  In this case, the Berlin theme ( ***beamerthemeBerlin.sty*** ) uses the mini frame outer theme ( ***beamerouterthememiniframes.sty*** ).

I then went into this outer theme and changed the definition of the *headline* and added a definition for the *frametitle*.  See my code below:

```
% Head Line
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=10.25ex,dp=4.5ex,left]{frametitle}
    \hspace{6pt}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
    \insertframetitle
    \vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vspace{-10pt}
}

% Frame Title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.4ex,dp=0.7ex,center]{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamerfont{headline}
    \insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
 % no subsection title for simplicity
}
```

And the results are shown below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great, I'm glad you've been able to modify the appropriate `.sty` file. Regards.