# Logo height equal to frametitle height in Beamer presentation gives error

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, macros, frame-title

This is with reference to the question [Adjust logo height to match \frametitle box height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401377/adjust-logo-height-to-match-frametitle-box-height)
This excellent solution works exactly in a way I want. However when I use the environment

```
\begin{block}
\end{block}
```

in any frame, it gives an error that `mybox` is already defined. So how the code can be modified to remove the error.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the mentioned error message.

Comment: I provided an answer to the original question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401377/adjust-logo-height-to-match-frametitle-box-height that fixes the issue. I guess we should close this one then?